# Segfault while copying string

Tags: c, string, struct, char

I'm trying to learn C, and now I'm playing with structures.
I have the following piece of code:

```
#include <string.h>

struct user {
  unsigned int utime;
  char *username;
};

void main()
{
  char username[] = "root";
  struct user *u;
  strcpy(u->username, username);
}
```

But, when I try to run it, it generates a Segmentation fault.
What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`u` is a pointer to a struct but you didn't allocate any memory for it yet. The line must be
 `struct user *u = malloc(sizeof(struct user))`. Additionally you will also have to allocate memory for the `username` pointer within your struct before calling `strcpy`.

Comment: Or just use a stack allocated `struct user` (but memory for `username` still required to by dynamically allocated).

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you should do when getting a crash (like segmentation fault), is to run your program in a debugger. It will help you pinpoint the location of the crash, and also let you examine variables to see what might have caused the crash.

However, in your case it's very simple:

```
struct user *u;
strcpy(u->username, username);
```

You haven't allocated memory for `u` or `u->username`, which means that `u` can point to anywhere in memory and the same for `u->username`.

Answer (score 0):

Two things

you have not allocated for the structure variable  "struct user *u;"

and also you have not allocated memory for *username in the structore

To work

```
 #include <string.h>
 struct user {
 unsigned int utime;
 char *username;
 };

 void main()
 {
    char username[] = "root";
    struct user *u=malloc(sizeof(struct user));
    u->username=malloc(strlen(username)+1);
    strcpy(u->username, username);
}
```

Please ignore if it has any syntax errors

Comment: In pure C, return value of `malloc` doesn't have to be type-casted.

Comment: @LihO I think we should, becuase malloc return type is void*. May be you ll get warning

Comment: When allocating memory for the string, it should be `strlen(username) + 1`, so you get space for the terminating `'\0'` too. Or use `strdup` instead of `malloc` and `strcpy`.

Comment: Have a look at [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Answer (score 0):

another way would be to use u as a simple variable: `struct user u`; and then access to utime or username with the ".", like this:

```
u.utime = ...;
u.username = ...;
```

Answer (score 0):

In parallel, you should also know about memory layout, and try reasoning what lives where. 
A starting point for this would be -[Stanford Pointers pdf](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/102/PointersAndMemory.pdf)
I would suggest,when you are learning and get stuck,try drawing the flow, memory access on paper and then go into the debugger. I didn't do this when I learnt C first- Memory Visualization is a  trait that seeems to make a person a better programmer/debugger- from what I have learnt from my colleagues/ read several articles online.